# iphone TBXML xml parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, parsing, tbxml

I'm using TBXML in my iphone application. I have an xml like the next one:

```
<detail>
    <title>My title</title>
    <subs>
       <sub>subCategory1</sub>
       <sub>subCategory2</sub>
       <sub>subCategory3</sub>
    </subs>
</detail>
```

I can successfully get the title and ONLY the first of subcategories. The code I'm using for getting the sub categories is the following:

```
NSMuttableArray *divs = [[NSMuttableArray] initWithCapacity:3];
TBXMLElement *subsElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"subs" parentElement:currentElement];
TBXMLElement *subElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"sub" parentElement:subsElement];
do {
    [divs addObject:[TBXML textForElement:subElement]];
    NSLog(@"%@ , %@", @"Got one subCategory " , divs.lastObject);
} while ((subsElement = subsElement->nextSibling));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but I would choose [`RaptureXML`](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML) over TBXML in a heartbeat for XML parsing on iOS. I'd take a look at it; parsing what you're trying to parse would be incredibly easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in your `where` statement.  I believe you meant to use `subElement` instead of `subsElement`.  So your code should be:

```
while ((subElement = subElement->nextSibling));
```

Comment: It was not a typo. It was the parent element type . But actually this is what it should have been.